# Resetting/reloading class attributes of nested class at runtime

Tags: python, python-3.x, class, oop, nested

I am using a nested class for "book keeping" purposes in Python 3. The class structure (highly simplified) looks something like this:

```
class BookKeeping:

    class ItemA:
        count = 0
        item_list = []

        @classmethod
        def add(cls, item_a):
            cls.count += 1
            cls.item_list.append(item_a)

    class ItemB:
        count = 0
        item_dict = {}

        ...
```

This class makes it convenient to keep track and to access some "global" properties of a system I am modelling. Having nested classes allows for clear namespacing. For instance, in any module I can `... import BookKeeping as BK` and check how many `ItemB` objects there are (`BK.ItemB.count`).

At some point in my program I would like to "reset" all class attributes, i.e. I would like to set `BookKeeping.ItemA.count` to 0 again and empty lists and dictionaries, etc.

Obviously, I could add a top-level class method like `BookKeeping.reset()` which resets all values "manually", like:

```
class BookKeeping:

    @classmethod
    def reset(cls):
        cls.ItemA.count = 0
        cls.ItemA.item_list = []
        cls.ItemB.count = 0

        ...
```

However, this seems to be an error-prone approach to me and it involves "maintenance" of this class (I might forget to reset some attributes). Please note, my real class is more complicated than the example I have provided.

What is the easiest way to reset all class attributes to their original state at runtime?

Comment: Can you just have a separate class (e.g. `BookKeepingSession` or something) that holds those values as *instance* properties rather than *class* properties? Then you could just create a fresh `BookKeepingSession` each time you want to do some unrelated `BookKeeping`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So upfront: Should you actually be doing this? Probably not.

I'd advise you to try to rethink your projects structure, actually, since global state is something which should usually be avoided.

If you still want to do it that way though...

Beware, some untested (!) arcane magic ahead:

```
import copy

class BookKeeping(object):
    __backup = {}

    class ItemA(object):
        ...

    class ItemB(object):
        ...

    @classmethod
    def reset(cls):
        for name, backup in cls.__backup.items():
            inner_cls = getattr(cls, name)
            for k, v in backup.items():
                setattr(inner_cls, k, copy.deepcopy(v))

for i in dir(BookKeeping):
    if not i.startswith("_"):
        obj = getattr(BookKeeping, i)
        BookKeeping.__backup[i] = {k: copy.deepcopy(getattr(obj, k)) for k in dir(obj)}
```

Additional notes: This is generally a tricky problem. But you could use the same technique for other nesting structures too, and handle types differently instead of handling the first level differently.

This is a problem because you don't want to `deepcopy` the types themselves, since that would duplicate the state across all live objects at that time and all new objects together with the current new global state.

Comment: Yes, I have realized that what I initially thought was a clean and convenient solution turns out to have a few flaws. I have refactored my code so that I don't have to deal with any global state anymore. I guess, the fact that Python makes it "ugly looking" and inconvenient should also be a strong indication that something is not very good. Thanks.